# input type range with focus method in firefox not woking

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, focus

In HTML code we are using input type range but the problem is when we use focus event then in Firefox its not working properly.

here is my code

```js
var p = document.getElementById("price"),
  res = document.getElementById("result");
test = document.getElementById("test");

p.addEventListener("input", function() {
  test.focus();
  test.value = "$" + p.value;
}, false);
```

```css
#result {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 1em">
  <h2>Price</h2> $51
  <input id="price" type="range" min="51" max="360" value="" />$360
</div>
<input type="text" name="test" value="" id="test" />
```

slider is not sliding smoothly in mozilla but its working fine in chrome

Comment: Whats the issue? Its working on firefox, "range" element behave different in firefox

Comment: please check this fiddle in mozilla https://jsfiddle.net/itruser/n7u5960f/1/ slider is not working smothly while in chrome slider working fine

Comment: I have made some improvements in my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When focus is shifted to input field then you will not be able to slide the slider.
Use following code to resolve it

```js
var p = document.getElementById("price"),
    res = document.getElementById("result"),
    test=document.getElementById("test"),
    timeout = null;

p.addEventListener("input", function() 
{
   test.value = "$" + p.value;
   clearTimeout(timeout);
   timeout = setTimeout(function(){ test.focus(); }, 400);
}, false);
```

```css
#result {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 1em">
    <h2>Price</h2>
    $51<input id="price" type="range" min="51" max="360" value="" />$360
</div>
<input type="text" name="test" value="" id="test"/>
```

Use `setTimeout` to focus on input field after a pause when slider was clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Firefox browser, because I ran your code and the slider is running smoothly on both the browsers(Chrome and Firefox) on my side and in your code you haven't given a reference to the JavaScript code. I assume that was present in your main code. Tell me if you are facing the problem even after updating.

Comment: i have firefox version 56.0 installed which version you are using.i think 56.0 is updated version. and i am still facing same problem